# How are keyword clouds constructed?

Tags: algorithm, math, search, nlp, keyword

How are keyword clouds constructed?
I know there are a lot of nlp methods, but I'm not sure how they solve the following problem:

You can have several items that each have a list of keywords relating to them.

(In my own program, these items are articles where I can use nlp methods to detect proper nouns, people, places, and (?) possibly subjects. This will be a very large list given a sufficiently sized article, but I will assume that I can winnow the list down using some method by comparing articles. How to do this properly is what I am confused about).

Each item can have a list of keywords, but how do they pick keywords such that the keywords aren't overly specific or overly general between each item?
For example, trivially "the" can be a keyword that is a lot of items.
While "supercalifragilistic" could only be in one.

I *suppose* that I could create a heuristic where if a word exists in *n%* of the items where n is sufficiently small, but will return a nice sublist (say 5% of 1000 articles is 50, which seems reasonable) then I could just use that. **However**, the issue that I take with this approach is that given two different sets of entirely different items, there is most likely some difference in interrelatedness between the items, and I'm throwing away that information.

This is very unsatisfying.

I feel that given the popularity of keyword clouds there must have been a solution created already. I don't want to use a library however as I want to understand and manipulate the assumptions in the math.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Thanks!

EDIT:

**freenode/programming/guardianx** has suggested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

tf-idf is ok btw, but the issue is that the weighting needs to be determined apriori. Given that two distinct collections of documents will have a different inherent similarity between documents, assuming an apriori weighting does not feel correct

**freenode/programming/anon** suggested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec

I'm not sure I want something that uses a neural net (a little complicated for this problem?), but still considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) is still a pretty standard method for extracting keywords. You can try a demo of [a tf-idf-based keyword extractor](http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/ker/) (which has the idf vector, as you say apriori determined, estimated from Wikipedia). A popular alternative is the [TextRank algorithm](https://rare-technologies.com/text-summarization-with-gensim/) based on PageRank that has an off-the-shelf implementation in [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/summarization/keywords.html).

If you decide for your own implementation, note that all algorithms typically need plenty of tuning and text preprocessing to work correctly.

The minimum you need to do is removing stopwords that you know that they never can be a keyword (prepositions, articles, pronouns, etc.). If you want something fancier, you can use for instance [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) to keep only desired parts of speech (nouns, verbs, adjectives). You can also include frequent multiword expressions (gensim has good function for automatic collocation detection), named entities (spacy can do it). You can get better results if you run coreference resolution and substitute pronouns with what they refer to... There are endless options for improvements.

Comment: Thanks. I kinda figured this was a "hard" problem, but the confirmation was a appreciated. Cheers!